# how to use graphql on react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

what am i suppose to do?
i have an old application where i was fetching data to and endpoint
now that i installed graphql i see that i need to create query (?) but how do i insert those query? do i still need the fetch?

this is App.js on `get_tasks` i want to see on screen just the name
so i do not need the ID, also, i'm not sure i need `done`, it is just a ceckbox that change SVG once is clicked and became true or false

```
import './App.css';
import Task from './Task';
import React from 'react';
import TaskForm from './TaskForm';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useQuery,gql} from '@apollo/client'

const GET_TASKS = gql`
  query GetTasks {
    tasks {
      name
      done
    }
  }
`;

const ADD_TASK = gql`
mutation AddTask($name: String!) {
  addTask(name: $name, done: false) {
    name
    done
    id
  }
}
`;

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(() => {
    const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    return storedTasks ?? [];
    //return storedTasks !== null ? storedTasks : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  function addTask(name) {  
    fetch('/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, done: false })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(message => {
        setTasks(prev => [...prev, message]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Si è verificato un errore durante la richiesta:', error);
      });
  }


  function removeTask(indexToRemove) {
    const index = tasks[indexToRemove]._id;
    fetch(`/graphql/delete/${index}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ done: true })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(message => {
        setTasks(prev => {
          return prev.filter((taskObject, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
        });
      });
  }
  
  function updateTaskDone(taskIndex, newDone) {
    const taskId = tasks[taskIndex]._id;
    const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
    updatedTasks[taskIndex].done = newDone;
  
    fetch(`/graphql/done/${taskId}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedTasks[taskIndex])
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
      })
  }
  
  function getMessage() {
    const percentage = numberTotal === 0 ? 0 : (numberComplete / numberTotal) * 100;
    if (percentage === 0) {
      return 'no tasks complete ';
    }
    if (percentage === 100) {
      return 'nice job! ';
    }
    return 'keep it up! ';
  }

  function renameTasks(index, newName) {
    const taskId = tasks[index]._id;
    fetch(`/graphql/rename/${taskId}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ newName: newName })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(message => {
        setTasks(prev => {
          const newTasks = [...prev];
          newTasks[index].name = newName;
          return newTasks;
        });
      });
  }

  const numberComplete = tasks.filter(t => t.done).length;
  const numberTotal = tasks.length;
    

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
      <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
      <TaskForm onAdd={addTask} />
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <Task
          {...task}
          key={index}
          onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
          onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
          onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
        />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is Graph.js, i have no idea what i m doing here i just followed the official guide

```
import App from './App'
import './index.css'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { gql , InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, ApolloClient} from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://flyby-router-demo.herokuapp.com/',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
);
```

Comment: You don't need `fetch` anymore, you need the `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks.